# rails not starting with the right version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, version

This must be a simple question, but I could not find the answer by browsing this forum.

When I check rails version, it shows version 3.2.8

```
user@domain.com [~/rails_apps]# rails -v
Rails 3.2.8
user@domain.com [~/rails_apps]#
```

But when I start the server, it runs version 2.3.11

```
user@domain.com [~/rails_apps/myapp]# script/server -p12011
=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 2.3.11 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:12011
/home3/user/rails_apps/myapp/config/environment.rb:45: warning: already initialized constant RAILS_ENV
NOTE: SourceIndex.new(hash) is deprecated; From /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:100:in `new'.
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What about when you run rails -v from within /rails_apps/myapp? If you're using RVM, is there a .rvmrc file in your myapp directory that's overriding your default ruby / rails? Is your rails version specified in your Gemfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you application is a 2.x rails application, you need to complete some changes before upgrade to 3.x

You may have a look to railscast  http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=27

On the other hand, you may want to upgrade your ruby to 1.9 using rvm 
rails 3.x work better with ruby 1.9

Comment: Thanks Alan. My issue was that I was trying to run an old 2.x app under rails 3.2.8

Answer (score 0):

Try following in your environment.rb

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '3.2.8' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
```

Comment: I tried that and now the server does not start at all
it throws an error usr/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:57:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- initializer (LoadError)

Answer (score 0):

Check your Gemfile and make sure it is pointing to rails 3.2.8

Then run `bundle` or `bundle update`

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this is an old app, built originally upon rails 2.3.1 and periodically upgraded insitu. Instead of `script/server`, try `rails server`

And make sure your Gemfile contains reference to rails 3.2.8